# Apache Mod_JK and Load Balancing

Tags: tomcat6, mod-jk

I am using Tomcat 6 and have some questions about Apache mod_jk as follows.

1. Do I have to install Apache webserver to use mod_jk ??
2. If I run applications on 2 servers under Tomcat and load balance between them using mod_jk, will this also check the availability of the applications i.e. will it only send requests to one server if the application is down on the other server ??
3. If it checks for availability do you need to have multicast available on the network.
4. We intend to use tomcat clustering as well, will this work with mod_jk ??
5. Is there anything else I could use to load balance with availability checking for tomcat running applications ??.

Any help will be appreciated.

Cheers
Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. Yes, unless you go out of your way to configure mod_jk not to do that.
3. No.
4. Yes, but it is not necessary.
5. Pretty much any H/W load-balancer, pretty much any web server that supports reverse proxy over HTTP or AJP.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Appreciate your help. Cheers Jeff

Answer (score 0):

You would be much better off using mod_proxy_ajp rather than mod_jk for this. It's much simpler to configure, none of those nasty JkMount things or the Tomcat listener that 'auto-configures' it for you, not, and it works a lot better too. It's also not deprecated, unlike mod_jk since Tomcat 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes , you must have a Apache/Httpd installed on your webserver, on this you can perform Load balancing using mod_jk/mod_cluster/mod_proxy. Hope currently you are using mod_jk.
2. You are right. This can be enable using session. If you want one session to a corresponding server instance only means you can enable session stickiness. And the load balancing will be based on the "lbfactor" which you are mentioning on the "worker.properties" of your mod_jk. "redirect" option for failover also available in worker.properties. Failover can be done from Application server side as well.
3. As far as I knew if you are enabling failover in Application server, multicast address will be available by default. Only thing you need to do is port opening.
4. Mod_jk will will work with clustring in tomcat/Jboss perfectly.
5. As I mentioned above in Answer "1" you can use any load balancing for tomcat.